# Why oclif-dev manifest command is executing source code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, oclif

`oclif-dev manifest` will execute your source code, why is this happening?

Step to reproduce:

1. run `npx oclif multi mynewcli`
2. create an `index.ts` file under root folder `src/app/index.ts`
3. you put `console.log("test...");` inside the `index.ts` file
4. import the file in your `src/commands/hello.ts`

```
import { Command } from "@oclif/command";
import * as fs from "fs-extra";
+ import "../app/index";

export default class extends Command {
  async run() {
  }
}
```

5. Now you run `yarn run prepack`, terminal shows

```sh
mynewcli % yarn run prepack
yarn run v1.22.4
$ rm -rf lib && tsc -b && oclif-dev manifest && oclif-dev readme
test...
```

I thought oclif will only transpile your source code, turns out it executes it, that's quite strange when you're building an npm library.

The current solution is to write everything inside a function.